# How to query/scan a table in DynamoDB using AND and OR in the same statement using python?

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I want to query a table on DynamoDB and using python. The thing with this query is that I want to use an AND and OR condition in the same query. I want the query to retrieve values from one column when the value is B or C.

I have the following table:

```
domain          validation_A        validation_B        validation_C
---------       -----------------   ---------------     ---------------
drene.com       pass                pass                pass
drene.com       pass                true                pass
drene.com       fail                pass                pass
```

In regular SQL expression I will use:

```
Select * 
from 
    ValidationTable 
where 
    domain = 'drene.com' and 
    validation_A = 'pass' and 
    (validation_B = 'pass' or validation_B = 'true')
```

I do not know how to do this in DynamoDB / Pythom

I tried the following:

```
response = table.scan(
                 IndexName="Date-index",
                 FilterExpression=Key('domain').eq('drene.com') & Attr('validation_A').eq('pass') & (Attr('validation_B').eq('pass') || Attr('validation_B').eq('true'))
```

)

But it is not working

I need the query bring me the first 2 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `|` instead of `||`

```
response = table.scan(
                 IndexName="Date-index",
                 FilterExpression=Key('domain').eq('drene.com') & Attr('validation_A').eq('pass') & (Attr('validation_B').eq('pass') | Attr('validation_B').eq('true'))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @horatiu-jeflea

This was exactly the issue